# Compare for existing values from 2 foreach loops?

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I have 2 foreach loop's where i get new results from my first db and i have second foreach where i get data from second db

My first foreach code is:

```
foreach($_existing_data_result as $result) {
echo $result->name.'<br>';
}
```

second foreach:

```
foreach($_new_data_result as $resultNew) {
echo $resultNew->name.'<br>';
}
```

I need to check on second foreach if result exist in first then ignore this result, i tried it with `in_array()`but i always see double names...

Comment: @degr If you don't know answer then don't even make an attempt to write, please.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You work with an objects, not with arrays. So, define array in first loop, and add values to it. Then use in_array().

Answer (score 0):

Second foreach, change it to this:

```
foreach($_new_data_result as $resultNew) {
    if (!in_array($resultNew,$_existing_data_result)) 
        echo $resultNew->name.'<br>';
}
```

This will work assuming that entire `$resultNew` object exist in `$_existing_data_result` and is identical.

Comment: I do it so, but i get still the same results, means i see also existing values.

Comment: @jExchange That's probably because objects aren't equal (two objects are equal, when they have the same properties with the same values). My example shows comparison of entire objects. If you want to check them by names only, look szapio's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use array_diff instead. Like

$new_array = array_diff($_existing_data_result, $_new_data_result);
```

Comment: So much memory waste. And also not, what OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

First get all names from the first array:

```
$names = array_map(
         create_function('$object', 'return $object->name;'),
         $app_items);
```

Then in second foreach check if the name exists in names array:

```
foreach($_new_data_result as $resultNew) {
    if(!in_array($resultNew->name, $names) {
        echo $resultNew->name.'<br>';
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$names = array();
foreach($_existing_data_result as $result) {
    echo $result->name.'<br>';
    $names[$result->name] = 1;
}

foreach($_new_data_result as $resultNew) { 
    if (!isset($names[$resultNew->name])) {
        echo $resultNew->name.'<br>';  
    }
}
```

Comment: better this - $names[] = $result->name;

Comment: @degr why? When I insert it as a value i have to use then `array_search` or `in_array` to check if this name was used, if i use it as a key i can just check `isset($names[$key]))` i think that checking specified key in array is faster than seraching whole array for specified value

Comment: in_array works also fast, not so fast as an isset or empty, but you will no feel difference. But, when you create assoc array, you spent some more memory - for array data, and for array hashkeys structure.

Comment: In most cases you will no feel difference, and you will no loose realy much memory, but this is 'semantic' question. I prefer make assoc array only if it necessary.